# Can't find root of 'stack level too deep' error when rendering partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've been stuck on this problem for a week. I will mail you a bottle of scotch if you can figure it out. Seriously, its come to bribery.

On `taxons#show` I'm rendering a products partial, `_products.html.erb`, which lists out all the products on a table to the show view of the taxons controller. When you click a product, by default the app will redirect the user to `products#show`, where the `_cart_local.html.erb` partial is rendered to display 'add to cart' options.

But on `taxons#show`, when a product is clicked I bring up a lightbox instead so the user doesn't have to leave the page. The lightbox code is inside `_products.html.erb`, and I'm trying to render `_cart_form.html.erb` inside of the lightbox. When I do, I get the 'stack level too deep' error and `taxons#show` won't render.

But the cart renders fine in `products#how`. I changed `@product` in the partial to just `product`. That didn't help. I rendered an empty partial and the page loads, which makes me think the problem is with `_cart_local` (but why would it render on `products#show`?).

Then I took out all of the code in between the opening form tag and the ending div/end tags and the page also rendered, which makes me think its in that block, but I can't wittle it down any further. I'm stuck

Here's the code for `_cart_local`, and if I take out the code between the `<!-- Here -->` and `<!-- AND HERE -->` comments, the page renders:

```
<%= form_for :order, :url => populate_orders_path do |f| %>
<div id="inside-product-cart-form" data-hook="inside_product_cart_form" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<% if product.has_variants? %>  <!-- HERE --> 
  <div id="product-variants" class="columns five alpha">
    <h6 class="product-section-title"><%= t(:variants) %></h6>
    <ul>
      <% has_checked = false
      product.variants.active(current_currency).each_with_index do |v,index|
        next if v.option_values.empty? || (!v.in_stock && !Spree::Config[:show_zero_stock_products])
        checked = !has_checked && (v.in_stock || Spree::Config[:allow_backorders])
        has_checked = true if checked %>
        <li>
          <%= radio_button_tag "products[#{product.id}]", v.id, checked, :disabled => !v.in_stock && !Spree::Config[:allow_backorders], 'data-price' => v.price_in(current_currency).display_price %>
          <label for="<%= ['products', product.id, v.id].join('_') %>">
            <span class="variant-description">
              <%= variant_options v %>
            </span>
            <% if variant_price v %>
              <span class="price diff"><%= variant_price v %></span>
            <% end %>
          </label>
        </li>
      <% end%>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end%>

<% if product.price_in(current_currency) and !product.price.nil? %>  
  <div data-hook="product_price" class="columns five <% if !product.has_variants? %> alpha <% else %> omega <% end %>">

    <div id="product-price">
      <h6 class="product-section-title"><%= t(:price) %></h6>
      <div><span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= product.price_in(current_currency).display_price %></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="add-to-cart">
      <% if product.on_sale? %>      
        <%= number_field_tag (product.has_variants? ? :quantity : "variants[#{product.master.id}]"),
          1, :class => 'title', :in => 1..product.on_hand, :min => 1 %>
        <%= button_tag :class => 'large primary', :id => 'add-to-cart-button', :type => :submit do %>
          <%= t(:add_to_cart) %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <%= content_tag('strong', t(:out_of_stock)) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
    <div id="product-price">
      <br>
      <div><span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= t('product_not_available_in_this_currency') %></span></div>
    </div>
<% end %> <!-- AND HERE -->   

</div>
<% end %>
```

And here is `_products.html.erb`, the file that is loading all the products, contains the lightbox, and has the render cart partial code:

```
<div class="overlay-container">
</div>
<%
 paginated_products = @searcher.retrieve_products if params.key?(:keywords)
 paginated_products ||= products
%>
<% if products.empty? %>
 <%= t(:no_products_found) %>
<% elsif params.key?(:keywords) %>
 <h6 class="search-results-title"><%= t(:search_results, :keywords =>  h(params[:keywords])) %></h6>
 <% end %>
 <div class="product_grid_container">
 <div class="grid_2"><%= image_tag("store/featured/#{@featured}.jpg") %></div>
 <% if products.any? %>
  <ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook>
  <% products.each do |product| %> 
   <% if product.on_display? %>
    <%# ******LIGHTBOX******* %>
     <div id="product_popup_<%= product.id %>" class="product_popup" data-popid="<%= product.id %>">
        <div class="related-products">
          <ul class="related_products_list" id="related_products_list_<%= product.id %>" data-listid="<%= product.id %>">
         <% @related_products.each do |related_product| %>
         <li class="related_products_item"><%= link_to large_image(related_product, :itemprop => "image", :data => {:imageid => related_product.id}, :id => "related_" + related_product.id.to_s, :class => "related_products_image dimmed"), url_for(related_product) %></li>
         <% end %>
    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-image">
        <%= large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image-popup") %>
        </div><!-- popup-image -->
        <div class="popup_right_content">
      <h2 class="popup-title"><%= product.name %></h2>
      <p class="popup-price">$<%= product.price %></p>
      <p><%= product.description %></p>
      <p class="popup-color">color:</p>
      <div class="popup-images" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
            <% if (product.images + product.variant_images).uniq.size > 1 %>
            <ul id="popup-thumbnails-taxon" class="thumbnails inline" data-hook>
            <% product.images.each do |i| %>
                <li class='tmb-all' id='tmb-<%= i.id %>'>
                    <%= link_to(image_tag(i.attachment.url(:small)), i.attachment.url(:popup), :class => 'tmb-all', :id => "tmb-#{i.id}") %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    </div><!-- popup-images -->
    </div><!-- popup_right_content -->
        <%= render 'spree/shared/cart_local', :locals => {:product => product} %>
 </div><!-- product_popup -->   
    <%# ******END LIGHTBOX******* %>
  <div class="grid_1">
  <li id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns product three <%= cycle("alpha", "secondary", "", "omega secondary", :name => "classes") %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="main-image" id="single_<%= product.id %>" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">

      <%= link_to large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image", :id => product.id), product_path(product), :remote => true, :html => {:class => "product_popup"}  %>
    </div><!-- main-image-->
    <div class="prod_info_box">
    <%= link_to truncate(product.name, :length => 50), product, :class => 'info', :itemprop => "name", :title => product.name %>
    <span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= product.price_in(current_currency).display_price %></span>

    <!-- BRINGS THUMBNAILS INTO TAXONS PAGE -- PULLED FROM _THUMBNAILS.HTML.ERB -->
    <div class="product-images" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
    <% if (product.images + product.variant_images).uniq.size > 1 %>
        <ul id="product-thumbnails-taxon" class="thumbnails inline" data-hook>
            <% product.images.each do |i| %>
                <li class='tmb-all' id='tmb-<%= i.id %>'>
                    <%= link_to(image_tag(i.attachment.url(:mini)), i.attachment.url(:normal), :class => 'tmb-all', :id => "tmb-#{i.id}") %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    </div><!-- product-images -->
    <!-- END THUMBNAILS INTO TAXONS PAGE -->
    <div id="product-description-taxon">
        <p><%= product.description %></p>
    </div><!-- product-description-taxon -->
    </div><!-- prod_info_box -->
  </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>

 <% reset_cycle("classes") %>
 </ul>
 <% end %>
 </div><!-- product_grid_container -->
 <% if paginated_products.respond_to?(:num_pages) %>
 <%= paginate paginated_products %>
 <% end %>
```

Let me know if you need anything else. i appreciate it.

Here's a link to the helpers, maybe the problem is there?
https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/v1.3.2/core/app/helpers/spree

Comment: Try installing pry. Drop a binding.pry into your code, boot up your app server, hit the page, and then you can step through it line-by-line to see how it's executing. That should get you on your way. Alternately, do a binary search of the problem code - remove half of it, test, if it works, remove the other half, repeat until you find the problem line. Then you'll know where to start.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with debuggers, but I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: Have you eliminated smaller portions of the "between here and here" template?

Comment: Yes, I feel like I've tried eliminating every line inside that block, but I still get the error. Only when I delete the whole thing does the page render.

Comment: My gut is that the problem is somewhere in your helpers; there's nothing obviously recursive in the code presented. A debugger session should help expose the loop, though.

Comment: Here's a link to the helpers if anyone is interested, I haven't looked closely at them so I'll try that. Thank you. https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/v1.3.2/core/app/helpers/spree

Answer (score 1):

In your `_products.html.erb` partial change that:

```
<%= render 'spree/shared/cart_local', :locals => {:product => product} %>
```

to that:

```
<%= render partial: 'spree/shared/cart_local', :locals => {:product => product} %>
```

and problem should be resolved.

Why? Because doing it as you have done it won't pass `locals` into partial and that's why you've received error, check it by yourself by removing `locals`. Of course the most interesting part is why you get `stack level too deep` error here, but I am unable to find answer for that now.

Oh, and debugger is your friend ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the difference between the two lines. Will you explain what you changed a bit more? And thank you so much for looking at this. It has been blowing my mind for months.